# Passing multiple arguments to send

Tags: ruby

I have a script that contains several methods, each with a varying number of arguments:

```
def method1

end

def method2(arg1)

end

def method3(arg1, arg2)

end

def method4(arg1, arg2, arg3)

end
```

I need to invoke these methods from the command line, which I am currently doing like so:

```
if ARGV.length == 1
  send(ARGV[0])
elsif ARGV.length == 2
  send(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
else
  send(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
end
```

Is there a one-line way of invoking the method and passing all the arguments (or none if there aren't any)?

Comment: Is the first argument of your script the name of the desired method? Could you give some more information about the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The first argument is the name of the method (they're not called `methodN`, I just gave them incrementing names in this example). Essentially I need a way of calling the individual methods from the command line and passing in the arguments that the method requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a splat operator, the unary prefix `*` operator that can be used in two places with dual meanings:

- in a *parameter list* in a method, block, or lambda definition, it means "package all remaining arguments into an `Array` and bind it to this parameter"
- in an *argument list* of a message send or a `yield` as well as the left-hand side of an assignment expression, it means "explode this `Array` into its individual elements as if they had been written individually in its place"

So, for example:

```
foo(*some_array)
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(some_array[0], some_array[1], some_array[2], …, some_array[some_array.size])
```

So, in your case, all you need to do is

```
send(*ARGV)
```

Note, that this obviously allows anyone who can manipulate `ARGV` to execute any arbitrary Ruby code, including but not limited to, erasing the hard disk, or launching the proverbial nuclear missiles. But, your original code has that same flaw. You really should perform validation here, but that is orthogonal to your question.

Comment: Many thanks, this is working perfectly. I have already verified the user input before `send(*ARGV)` is called so all is well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
send("method#{ARGV.size+1}", *ARGV)
```

As an example:

```
def method1
  puts "METHOD 1. No parameter"
end

def method2(arg1)
  puts "METHOD 2. #{arg1}"
end

def method3(arg1, arg2)
  puts "METHOD 3. #{arg1}, #{arg2}"
end

def method4(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  puts "METHOD 4. #{arg1}, #{arg2}, #{arg3}"
end

args = %w(a b c)

send("method#{args.size+1}", *args)
# METHOD 4. a, b, c
```

It's not really clean or robust, though.

You can use splat operator (`*args`) for both method definition and call:

```
def generic_method(*args)
  puts "Generic method has been called with #{args.size} parameters: #{args.inspect}"
  # Add logic here
end

generic_method
# Generic method has been called with 0 parameters: []
generic_method('a')
# Generic method has been called with 1 parameters: ["a"]
generic_method('a', 'b', 'c')
# Generic method has been called with 3 parameters: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

No need for `send` anymore!

Comment: I kinda doubt that his methods are _actually_ named method1, method2, ... :)

Comment: actually, method name is one of the args.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Question isn't so clear about that. Let's ask the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As Ursus suggests (but his answer is gone now) you can do this very simply with

```
send(*ARGV)
```

But this is potentially dangerous as this works with any method in `ARGV[0]` so you should have some mechanism to ensure only certain methods are allowed

```
filter_send(*ARGV)

def filter_send(method, *arguments)
  send(method, *arguments) if good_method?(method)
end

def good_method?(sent_method)
  %w(method1 method2 method3 method4).include?(sent_method.to_s)
end
```

so now you can do...

```
filter_send(*ARGV)
```

...and be confident that dangerous methods can't be passed